# Enable Publishing Options button without SharePoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, excel, excel-services

We use MS Office 2010 Standard, and some users will be publishing spreadsheets from Excel to SharePoint (2010). We have discovered, however, that the Publishing Options button only appears in the Send to SharePoint area if SharePoint Designer 2010 is installed on the computer.

Is there any way to enable this button for users without requiring that everyone install SharePoint Designer?